# Find detail of 404 error on Heroku

Tags: heroku

So, I'm kind of new to Heroku. I have a small forum for a private community. New Relic tells me there was a 404 this afternoon. I want to find out the details of the request that returned that 404. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the logs on Heroku with `heroku logs`.

However, Heroku only allows access to the most recent 1500 lines.

> Heroku only stores the last 1500 lines of log history. If you’d like
>   to persist more than 1500 lines, use a logging add-on.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-history-limits

You should install [one of the many logging add ons](https://addons.heroku.com/?q=logging) so that you can keep more log history.